# CSS:Confuse about element's width in percentage

Tags: css, width

Suppose I have an parent element without specific width, it has four children elements:

```
<div>
    <a href>A</a>
    <a href>B</a>
    <a href>C</a>
    <a href>D</a>
</div>
```

each the child have a width set to `width:25%;`

```
div {
    margin:0 auto;
    max-width: 880px;
}
a {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 25%;
}
```

However, the last element `D` always have word wrap, http://jsfiddle.net/5d884606/

But I think they should stay in the same line and have the equal width. Why this happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because elements with `display: inline-block;` will get 'extra' margin when you have a `font-size` set on the parent element that is higher than 0. Set the `font-size` of the parent to `0`, and set it back the way you want it on the child elements

```
div {
    margin:0 auto;
    max-width: 880px;
    font-size: 0;
}
a {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

**Example:**
http://jsfiddle.net/skeurentjes/5d884606/2/

Comment: Thank you very much.But I still confuse why W3C will rule it like this, why the child `inline-block` element would add extra margin.Does it count as a bug?

Comment: inline-block has the same behaviour as inline, which is used to handle the the text. U can see it just like the spacing between words. Don't know if it's a bug. It's just the way it is ;)

Answer (score 0):

it is because `inline-block` adds a `4px margin`,

so instead of `25%` , if you change the width to `24%`, they would all be on the same line.

see updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5d884606/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5d884606/4/)**

CSS:

```
div {
    margin:0 auto;
    max-width: 880px;
    background-color:#ccc;
}
a {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width: 25%;
    background-color:#f00;
}
```